# Is limit of sum of logarithms same as limit of logarithm of product when all terms are additionally indeterminate

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given:

1. Let $A(N) = |\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n$|, $B(N) = |\sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n$| and $C(N) = |\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_n$| where $a_n, b_n, c_n \in \mathbb{R}$
2. $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} A(N)\cdot B(N) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} C(N)$
3. $A(N)\cdot B(N) \ne C(N)$ when $N$ is finite

I think the following should be provable provided all limits exist (they may have indeterminate form or not):
$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log A(N)}{N} + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log B(N)}{N} = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log C(N)}{N}  $$

The trouble I am running into is I think I cannot use limit of quotient = quotient of limits rule because the limit of denominator diverges. I can convert the quotient into product using 1/N as a factor. I am not sure if it is acceptable considering $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} =0$

Here is my attempt:

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log A(N)}{N} + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log B(N)}{N}$$

$$=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot\log A(N) + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot \log B(N) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log A(N) + \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log B(N) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot ( \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log A(N) +  \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log B(N)) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot ( \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} ( \log A(N) + \log B(N) )) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot ( \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log (A(N) \cdot B(N) )) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot (\log (\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} (A(N) \cdot B(N) ))) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot (\log (\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} C(N)) $$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \cdot (\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \log C(N))$$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{N} \cdot \log C(N))$$

$$= \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log C(N)}{N}$$

Does this work? If not are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here but many times when doing operations with limits you must ask yourself if the operation is valid and this usually requires one to consider whether the limit exists. For instance, when you say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \log(A(n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\log(A(n))$ you assume that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\log(A(n))$ exists.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri thanks for your comment. Restricting $A(N), B(N), and C(N)$ to convergent series, do you see any problem?

Comment: Only if they are all positive past a certain $N$ can you *consider* taking the limit. Even then, if they converge to $0$ then the limit of the logarithm does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{u_N}{N}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\lim_{N\to\infty}u_N$, as the RHS is $0$ times what may be infinite or undefined. Your original problem admits the counterexample$$\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=\exp-N^2,\,\sum_{n=1}^Nb_n=\exp N^2,\,\sum_{n=1}^Nc_n=1+\frac1N.$$In this case $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\ln A_N}{N}+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\ln B_N}{N}$ is undefined because the terms are respectively $-\infty,\,\infty$.